# PHP : timezone_name_from_abbr() always returns false

Tags: php

**Code**

```
$c_tme = -330;
$this->_CLIENT_T_Z = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $c_tme*-60, 1);
if( $this->_CLIENT_T_Z == FALSE ){
    $this->_CLIENT_T_Z = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $c_tme*-60, 0);
}
```

This code is working fine in local. But after uploading to server it always returns false. Is that because of any coding issue?

Comment: Is there a timezone database file configured on your server that contains the relevant info? Check `phpinfo()` for that, and also see what `timezone_abbreviations_list()` has to tell.

Comment: its empty. So i did it manually.